# Can view files on google drive using their python api, but can't download them

Tags: google-api

So currently I am trying to get this example working from google drive's API: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads.  I'd like to be able to pull files out of my drive.  However, whenever I try and run the code from the first example, I get the following error:

> https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0BzJHBBMMxZNlQTlMYlV6RXBlbTg?alt=media returned "The user has not granted the app 543723074819 read access to the file 0BzJHBBMMxZNlQTlMYlV6RXBlbTg.">

I suspect I am just not configuring my credentials correctly (I made them by going to the dev console, clicking google drive and basically checking all the boxes.)  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if any poor confused soul has this problem, it's probably because you changed something in your program without first wiping out ~/.credentials.